# Manipulate Blender Meta information by Three.js

Tags: three.js, blender

I need to display some blender models using webGL. Well what I need to know is, **is it possible to add some meta information in Blender that we can manipulate using webGL ?**

e.g:

- Add in **Blender** a meta information about the lights location
- Using **Three.js** (webGL), putting lights in place of lights meta information from Blender

I hope I could express my need well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than meshes, Three.js' Blender exporter supports exporting lights and cameras (and apparantly non-mesh, pure Object3Ds) out-of-the box. Just check the corresponding options together with the Scene export option during exporting and use the [SceneLoader](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/55/#Reference/Loaders/SceneLoader) for loading. If you need other than that, you'd need to modify the exporter.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender you can name the objects and in Three you can search for objects, lights and cameras by name. You can then hide, delete, replace,  modify or clone those objects.

I have done this with Collada/DAE scenes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you have any link for documentation, tutorial ?